# Extracting very specific part of a string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string for example "Hello_World_1_x.txt" and I want to take what ever is after the last underscore and before the .txt. The .txt will always be there as well as the underscore but there could be many underscores. I used .split() to get rid of the last 4 characters but I want only whats after the LAST underscore. So far my regex only gives me whats after the first underscore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use standard string functions:

```
var result = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, s.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/_([^_.]*)\.txt$/i
```

Using `String#match`:

```
 var r = 'Hello_World_1_x.txt'.match(/_([^_.]*)\.txt$/)[1];
 //=> x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regular expressions, give this a try:

```
[^_]*(?=\.txt)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Here's a [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Xd8KdNAYqqkcp42p) and a JSFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5gpqt/).

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

EDIT: Misread the strings name - now updated:

```
function getLastValue(string, splitBy) {
  var arr = string.split(splitBy);
  return arr[arr.length-1].split(".")[0]
}


getLastValue("Hello_World_1_x.txt","_"); //"x"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "Hello_World_1_x.txt";
var a = s.split(/[._]/);
console.log( a[a.length-2] );   // "x"
```

This says, *"Split the string on either periods or underscores, and then pick the part that is next-to-last"*". Alternatively:

```
var s = "Hello_World_1_x.txt";
var a = s.split(/[._]/);
a.pop(); var last = a.pop();
console.log( last );   // "x"
```

Comment: What about if there is an additional '.'? "Hello_world_1_x.x.txt"

Comment: @DairyLea In that unlikely case then, as you imply, this answer would not return what we imagine the user wants.